# Swagger Basic Authentication Issue

Tags: basic-authentication, swagger, swagger-ui

i am using [Swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) version 2.1.4, i have hosted it locally and provided it my own **Json** file and **API** it opens the document fine and lists all the method in the json file, after i put basic authentication in it, i did all changes in the **Index.html** changes are

```
  function addApiKeyAuthorization(){
var key = "Basic ************";
if(key && key.trim() != "") {

    var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", key, "header");
    window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("Authorization", apiKeyAuth);
    swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("Authorization", apiKeyAuth);


 }
}
```

it gives error, [image]screen shot attached.

it gives error when it tries to authenticate swagger get data of the method with anonymous permissions from same **API**.

When i hit the **Curl** from the command prompt it bring results. It only fails in **Swagger**

> Did Swagger have any issue with basic Authentication?

Comment: Please share the specification that you have that is giving this issue.

Comment: @fehguy: Issue is Solved it was not Server side issue and nor the client side side, swagger was sending "options" packet to API which was not allowed, and due to no response it was shoeing this, i allowed it and it start working, and authentication was fine.

Comment: great, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

You might open up Fiddler and make the request via the browser, like you said you did, and then make the request using Swagger 2.0.  Compare the requests and make 100% sure the request headers and url are the same.